# jQuery file upload: Setting headers for HTTP OPTIONS in cross browser upload

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jquery-file-upload, http-options-method

Using jQuery file upload, I'm uploading a file to a third-party server that requires token authentication for all incoming requests. Before the upload, the browser sends an OPTIONS request to check for cross-domain authorization. That request fails with a 401 because it doesn't contain the token. How can I add an "Authorization: Token " header to that request?

In curl this works:
`curl -X OPTIONS https://api.example.com -H 'Authorization: Token <TOKEN>'`

I tried the following three options, without luck:

```
  $("#file-upload").fileupload({
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + TOKEN);
      },
      xhrFields: {
        "Authorization": "Token " + TOKEN
      },
      requestHeaders: {
        "Authorization": "Token " + TOKEN
      },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work the remote endpoint must explicitly set the CORS response header to allow Authorization using in the OPTIONS request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

If the remote server you are trying to upload to doesn't set this header, your cross domain AJAX call won't be able to send an `Authorization` request header.

Comment: That's not the problem. I get a 401 with the OPTIONS request because I didn't include any Authorization headers in my request, and I don't know how to do so with this plugin.